# GCC: "__unused__" vs just "unused" in variable attributes

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

According to [GCC's own documentation on variable attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html), the correct syntax for declaring an attribute unused is `__attribute__((unused))`.

However, in many examples and other code online, I frequently see `__attribute__((__unused__))` instead, and they appear to both work.

Is there a reason for either specifying or omitting the `__` in either case?  Does it make any difference, and is there a preferred version?  Are there any situations where using one and not the other might cause problems?

Presumably the same applies to other attribute parameters as well?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At the top of [the very page you linked](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html), it tells you:

> You may also specify attributes with ‘`__`’ preceding and following
>   each keyword. This allows you to use them in header files without
>   being concerned about a possible macro of the same name. For example,
>   you may use `__aligned__` instead of `aligned`.

Identifiers containing double underscores (`__`) are reserved to the implementation. Hence no user program could legally define them as macros.